# Shows up in "Processes" not "Applications"

Tags: powershell, filemaker, taskmanager

I am working on a scheduled powershell to restart a certain program if it is off.

I can check if it shows up in the processes (get-process) and can check its cpu number but sometimes the program appears in the processes but is not fully running- it doesn't show up in "Applications" on the task manager and isn't a window I can alt tab through.

Is there a back end to the application tab where I can get a list of that?

The program is filemaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether the process has [an associated Window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39708290/712649):

```
$filemaker = Get-Process filemaker
if($filemaker.MainWindowHandle -eq 0){
    # Not fully running
}
```