# C# How to determinate if Process is background process or not

Tags: c#, process

How to determinate if one process with GetProcess(Name) is background process or not ?

Comment: Define "background process".

Comment: You mean background thread? All process are background

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET How to check if a Windows process is running as an "App" or as a "Background application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708184/net-how-to-check-if-a-windows-process-is-running-as-an-app-or-as-a-backgroun)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `Process` class, you can examine the `MainWindowHandle` property. It will be `IntPtr.Zero` if the process doesn't have a window.

Comment: That doesn't eliminate Console apps. Also make sure that app is up and running first; even a Windows Forms app starts up without a _created_ window.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a better way to determine if the process is running background.
For example, it can happend, that MSAccess process doesn't close correctly. The MSAccess.exe process appears under background processes list even if has MainWindowHandle...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).