# About getting background process in C#

Tags: c#, process, background, window, task

I am making a program with some functions same as task manager's. What I want to do is just getting processes that have window and show them in a ListView like this. How can I check whether a process is a "app" (having window) or it is a background process.

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you stuck? Your question is pretty broad. Anyway your feature to differ betwen an app and a background-process is pretty vague. What kind of "window" you refer to? Isn´t a console-window also a window? What about native apps? What about WPF-apps? What about Java-executables? There are so many apps and programs that have some graphical component, that it´s pretty unclear which ones you refer to.

Comment: Work backwards.  You can enumerate the windows on a desktop, and then find the apps associated with each window.  I'm not sure if there is a .NET call, but `EnumWindows` has been around forever: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows

Comment: Can't you just check if MainWindowHandle is zero or not? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle

Comment: In Summary, what I want to do is categorizing all processes into 2 kind: " App" and "Background processes"  with the same way as task manger do. Like the picture in the question.

Comment: Duplicate of this question I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708184/net-how-to-check-if-a-windows-process-is-running-as-an-app-or-as-a-backgroun

Comment: @RandRandom I tried,  but it actually doesn't work exactly as a task manager do.

Answer (score 1):

If `MainWindowHandle` is 0, then it is a background task:

```
var process = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (var x in process)
{
    var window = x.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();
    bool isbackground = window > 0;
    Console.WriteLine($"Name : ${x.ProcessName.ToString()}   |Background : ${isbackground.ToString()}");
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. In addition, I want to know whether a process has visible window or not, and whether it is mark as critical or not. How can i get these infor in C#. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a windows handle, you can tell everything about the window (like whether it's hidden or not, as well as its placement (sometimes things get hidden by being placed off-screen - Windows has many tricks).  I have no idea what you mean by "critical" - and I don't see it in your original question (or in the screen shot)..  Good luck exactly reproducing Task Manager.  Microsoft has *very* good institutional knowledge about all things Windows - particularly the ins and outs of processes, windows, etc.